# how to enable custom list internal id in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

NetSuite custom list internal id for values is disabled by default. is there a way i can add my own id for the custom list values.

i am trying to create a custom record to save expense clain details for employee. i have many list to hold datas for diffrent category. it will be better insted of 1,2,3 i can give my own Internal id.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Brett's answer gives you a method by which you can change the text ID of the *list*, but you cannot change the internal ID of the list's *values*.  This id is set automatically by NetSuite (or probably the underlying database) and is needed to ensure consistency of data within the application.  Instead, consider converting the list into a custom record, which will allow you to create another field to use as an external ID, which you can add/update by CSV import (you need to use the Internal ID as key when doing this).

Once converted to a record, you could also add a new field to use as a reference, depending on how you're using it.

To convert to a record, simply check the Convert to Custom Record box on the list page shown in your screenshot and click Save.

Comment: good catch. I didn't even see that the OP had highlighted the field values. Perils of answering on a phone.

Comment: Give the apparent use case the other benefit of converting to a custom record is that you could add range fields so that you can apply the correct field value based on the inbound value of the claim rather than having to parse the list label

Answer (score 1):

Click the “Change Id” button
Enter the new value. 
Click Save

Note: Netsuite will prefix the value you enter with ‘customlist’

Comment: its not about custom list internal ID, it is about internal id for values.